# select an unknown class in jquery

Tags: jquery

we write this code in Js for select an class(whitn't a class or Id name):

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
x[2].style.color="red"
```

Please note x!
But how we do it in jquery?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `.css()` with selecting `.eq()` to choose like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p:eq(2)").css("color","red");
   //OR
    $("p").eq(2).css("color","red");
});
```

Consider that x[2] will select the 3rd 'p' tag as eq(2) do.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('p').eq(2).css({color:red})
```

`$('p')` selects all `<p>` elements.
`.eq(2)` selects the third `<p>` element.
`.css({color:red})` adds the styles to the selected p tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("p").eq(2).css("color","red");
```

Comment: What have you changed Hinata and why ? let me know

Comment: This is a example of chaining in jQuery.